# MouseEvent problem AWT Java

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent

I'm simply trying to I’m simply trying to draw a circle in the same location as mouse click, but I can’t get it to work. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class LineApp
{
    public static void main ( String args[])
    {
        MainWindow mainWdw = new MainWindow();
    }
}

class MainWindow extends Frame
{
    private Point recPoint;
    private boolean mouseClick;


    MainWindow()
    {
        mouseClick = false;
        setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        setSize( 400,300 );
        setLocation( new Point( 300,300));

        addComponentListener(new ComponentCatcher());
        addWindowListener(new WindowCatcher());
        addMouseListener(new MouseCatcher());

        setVisible( true );
    }

    public void paint( Graphics gc )
    {
        gc.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        if(mouseClick)
        {
            gc.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            gc.fillOval(recPoint.x, recPoint.y, 30,30);
        }

    }

    class WindowCatcher extends WindowAdapter
    {
        public void windowClosing( WindowEvent evt)
        {
            evt.getWindow().dispose();
            System.exit (0);
        }
    }

    class ComponentCatcher extends ComponentAdapter
    {
        public void componentResized (ComponentEvent evt)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    class MouseCatcher extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousedPressed ( MouseEvent evt)
        {
           Point mousePt = new Point();
           mousePt = evt.getPoint();
           recPoint = new Point(mousePt.x,mousePt.y);
           mouseClick = true;
           repaint();
        }
}
```

}

Comment: What *specifically* is not working about your code?  Is the circle appearing at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method in `MouseAdapter` is called [`mousePressed`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mousePressed%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29), not `mousedPressed`.

The [`@Override`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)-annotation can help you to avoid errors like that. If you would have used

```
  @Override
  public void mousedPressed ( MouseEvent evt)
  {
      ...
```

your code would not have compiled.